# Using join fetch hint more than 1 time at the same level causes exception (JPA, Eclipselink)

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, fetch

While this code works as expected

```
    TypedQuery<Subject> query = em.createQuery("select s from Subject s",   Subject.class);
    query.setHint(QueryHints.FETCH, "s.person");
    query.setHint(QueryHints.FETCH, "s.person.att");
    query.setHint(QueryHints.FETCH, "s.person.att.name");
    System.out.println(query.getResultList().size());
```

adding another hint to fetch another attribute at the same level as "name"

```
query.setHint(QueryHints.FETCH, "s.person.att.title");
```

causes strange exception:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-6044] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: The primary key read from the row [DatabaseRecord(
NAME.IDNAME => 1
NAME.NAME => null)] during the execution of the query was detected to be null.  Primary keys must not contain null.
Query: ReadObjectQuery(name="title" referenceClass=Title )
at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException.nullPrimaryKeyInBuildingObject(QueryException.java:928)
...
```

(It does not matter which attributes and in what order are used).

Comment: Either there is a bug, or somehow a composite pk value is incorrectly returning a null which is unexpected.  What is the SQL that is issued for your query, and what are the results?

Comment: I actually simplified the example here, which I probably shouldn't have. Though the only difference in my project is even one additional level of nesting. I've been playing with this more and it seems like when properties are nested to maximum level of 4 or if there is only one fetched attribute at the bottom level, everythings works OK, otherwise this crazy exception is thrown.